# How to set default desktop enviroment 15.10

Tags: login, lightdm, desktop-environments

Things appear to have changed from 14.04. Then, my last desktop environment was remembered and I did not have to select one each time from the greeter login. One user defaulted to cinnamon, another to ubuntu (unity).

With 15.10, the greeter login ALWAYS defaults to ubuntu. /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf contains:

```
[Seat:*]
user-session=ubuntu
```

and this always appears as the default selection, even though $HOME/.dmrc for a user contains:

```
[Desktop]
Session=cinnamon
```

I suppose I can make the default ALWAYS e.g. cinnamon by changing 50-ubuntu.conf, but that still doesn't give me a per-user default. It seems like the current implementation renders $HOME/.dmrc useless.

Is there a way to set a per-user default for desktop environment with 15.10?